# How can I changing scene without losing data?

Tags: java, netbeans, scenebuilder

I have an image viewer application, and I'd like to change scenes from normal screene to full screen.

```
@FXML
    public void fullScreen(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent home_page_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("image_view.fxml"));
        Scene home_page_scene = new Scene(home_page_parent);    
        String css = this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm();    
        home_page_scene.getStylesheets().add(css); 
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        app_stage.setScene(home_page_scene);
        app_stage.show();
        app_stage.setFullScreen(true);
        percentageChecker = true;
    }
```

I figured this out with the method above. But I have one really big problem. Every time, when I changeing scenes, the picture disappeare from my imageView. I know why, but I don't know, how can I prevent this.

I've been programming in java just two weeks ago, so please be patient, and very understandable. Thank you!

(This code is in my view controller.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it. My controller will be my main java with start method.